# Python Subplot : Plotting multiple dataframe into single plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I am currently working on a dataset with multiple dataframes. The code was like this, currently there are 8 individual plots. I want to integrate all of them into a single plot, so that it is much easier to look at it. The data was taken from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fedesoriano/stroke-prediction-dataset)

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Untuk melihat semua kolom data
pd.set_option('display.width', 400)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 12)

#buat dataset dari csv
df = pd.read_csv("data mentah.csv")
df.sort_values(by=['age'], inplace = True)

df = df.drop("work_type", axis =1)
df = df.drop("ever_married", axis =1)

age0 = df[df["age"].between(0,9)]
age10 = df[df["age"].between(10,19)]
age20 = df[df["age"].between(20,29)]
age30 = df[df["age"].between(30,39)]
age40 = df[df["age"].between(40,49)]
age50 = df[df["age"].between(50,59)]
age60 = df[df["age"].between(60,69)]
age70 = df[df["age"].between(70,79)]
age80 = df[df["age"].between(80,90)]

end0 = df[df["age"].between(0,9)]
end10 = df[df["age"].between(0,19)]
end20 = df[df["age"].between(0,29)]
end30 = df[df["age"].between(0,39)]
end40 = df[df["age"].between(0,49)]
end50 = df[df["age"].between(0,59)]
end60 = df[df["age"].between(0,69)]
end70 = df[df["age"].between(0,79)]
end80 = df[df["age"].between(0,90)]

df4 = pd.DataFrame(df["stroke"])
df00 = df4[0:len(age0)]
df01 = df4[len(age0)+1:len(end10)]
df02 = df4[len(age10)+1:len(end20)]
df03 = df4[len(age20)+1:len(end30)]
df04 = df4[len(age30)+1:len(end40)]
df05 = df4[len(age40)+1:len(end50)]
df06 = df4[len(age50)+1:len(end60)]
df07 = df4[len(age60)+1:len(end70)]
df08 = df4[len(age70)+1:len(end80)]

print(df4.sum())
print(df00.count())

fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) 
fig_dims = (2, 4)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (0, 0))
df00.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 0-9')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (0, 1))
df01.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 10-19')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (0, 2))
df02.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 20-29')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (0, 3))
df03.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 30-39')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (1, 0))
df04.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 40-49')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (1, 1))
df05.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 50-59')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (1, 2))
df06.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 60-69')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (1, 3))
df07.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 70-79')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)

plt.subplot2grid(fig_dims, (1, 3))
df08.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='proporsi stroke umur 80-89')
plt.xticks(rotation = 0)
```

Or there are another alternative in grouping and counting a grouped data without using "len"?
Thank you

Comment: You need to provide sample data.

Comment: how I attach my data into my question?

Comment: You want all the barplots in one plot , like on top of each other?